# How to create a standalone pip package (all deps included)

Tags: python, pip

What's the best way to create a standalone pip package, that would run on any machine with bare package installed?

Say, I want to package [pelican](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pelican/3.1.1) so that it'll run at all computers with python installed (assume for a moment that all dependencies are pure python).

Comment: You mean by running `pip install pelican` it'll install everything properly? Or do you need to include the installation of `pip` itself as well?

Comment: No. I mean, give the clients a package `pelican-all-deps-included.tgz` that they can use with a bare python installation. They shouldn't even need `pip`.

Answer (score 7):

There are two solutions in my mind: [bundles](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#bundles) and `pip install --no-install` trick.

**Using `bundles`:**

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ venv/bin/pip install pelican
$ venv/bin/pip freeze > all-packages.txt
$ venv/bin/pip bundle allpackages.pybundle -r all-packages.txt
```

(I created `venv` to have a clean environment and `all-packages.txt` contain only what pelican needs)

And you just need to distribute `allpackages.pybundle`, and who wants those packages that must do:

```
$ venv/bin/pip install allpackages.pybundle -r all-packages.txt
```

---

**Using `pip install --no-install`:**

pip can download all packages to a directory, and you can distribute those packages. Assuming you have `all-packages.txt` containing all the packages you need to distribute, you can use the `--no-install` with `--download-dir` options:

```
$ mkdir tarballs
$ venv/bin/pip install --no-install --download-dir=tarballs -r all-packages.txt
```

If you use the last trick and wants to install those packages using pip:

```
$ venv/bin/pip install --no-deps --no-index tarballs/*
```

The option `no-deps` is needed because pip looks for dependencies before installing the wnated package. I used `--no-index` just to show you pip does not needs to go to PyPI to find anything, and you don't even need internet connection in that step.

Comment: I don't want people to install the bundle. I want them to just use it, with no installation.

Comment: @HBase, if you use the `pip install --no-install` solution `tarballs` directory contains all your packages. You can unpack them and run `python setup.py install` inside each package directory. The problem with this approach is dependency order.

Comment: I don't want to run `python setup.y install`, I want to run the program and have it work.

Comment: If that's your case, I only have PYTHONPATH in mind. After unpacking all tarballs, try `for p in $(ls tarballs); do export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$p; done`, and then use python as you wish. I am not sure about this solution, because I have never tried it. But it makes total sense to me. Good luck.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if any of your packages have C extensions or anything that needs to be compiled somehow, that `PYTHONPATH` trick would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note: 
PIP version 7 + has replaced (at least that is the version with which I tested this command)

```
--no-install
```

option with

```
--download or -d
```

So to just download all the packages required for pelican as explained in the example above, you would run:

```
pip install -d tarballs pelican
```